# how to remove active state on other links when another link is active

Tags: jquery, css

I only want one link to be in an active state. How do I remove link's active state when I click on other links to make that specific link active instead? I'm using jQuery addClass and removeClass

Here's what I've got

```
<style>.active {border-bottom: 3px solid #DB3030;}</style>

<div class="link"><a href="#scroll1" class="scroll">Link 1</a></div>
<div class="link"><a href="#scroll2" class="scroll">Link 2</a></div>
<div class="link"><a href="#scroll3" class="scroll">Link3</a></div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".link a").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link a").click(function() {
    $('.link a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #DB3030;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link"><a href="#scroll1" class="scroll">Link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="link"><a href="#scroll2" class="scroll">Link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="link"><a href="#scroll3" class="scroll">Link3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(".link a").removeClass('active');
```

Then

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

So your full code (and optimized);

```
var links = $(".link a"); // Cache the links for better performance
$(links).click(function() {
    $(links).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following

```
var links = $(".link a"); 
$(links).click(function() {
    $(links).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```